# Move one pg database from one app to an other app in heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have an app running on heroku. This app has a database, I need to move this database from one app to an other app. I was thinking in creating a backup, and then uploading that backup into the new app but I'm sure there must be something easier to do but I can't find how to do it!

My db is the 9 dolar/month, the basic one...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need - just update the `DATABASE_URL` config var on your new app with that of the old one.

Comment: Yes, I have already check that, but what will happen when the other app is closed?

Comment: If it's a Paid PG DB you should be fine, but worth checking with Heroku support.  Alternatively to be sure, transfer the data to a new DB  https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer